# Using a custom cache serializer with Windows Server App Fabric

Tags: serialization, appfabric, appfabric-cache

It seems it is possible to use custom cache serializer with Azure AppFabric ([Custom Serialization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jagan_peri/archive/2012/08/23/custom-serializer.aspx) by Jagan Peri).

Is there any possibility to use custom serializer with Windows Server AppFabric caching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible.
AppFabric Caching  use the NetDataContractSerializer (with deflate compression if configured).
I have check this point by myself after decompiling client assemblies.

Comment: Thanks! Jagan Peri [confirmed this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jagan_peri/archive/2012/08/23/custom-serializer.aspx#10347599).

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using following workaround:

1) implement your own custom serialization
2) serialize your objects before putting into cache
3) add string object into cache

Wojtek

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this approach, but unfortunatelly it was too slow for my needs

Comment: you may use protobuf for that